# get concatenated tuple type; combine result_of and tuple_cat

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples, return-type

i want to return the result of `std::tuple_cat` from my function but i fail to deduce the return type

```
#include <tuple>

struct H {
    typedef std::tuple<int,int> tuple_type;
    tuple_type a {1,2};
};

template <typename tuple_holder_type, typename B>
???
func(tuple_holder_type h, B b) {
    return std::tuple_cat(h.a,std::make_tuple(b));
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    auto h = H();
    auto b = 3;
    auto c = func(h,b);
    return 0;
}
```

i tried to combine `std::result_of` and `std::tuple_cat` like this

```
typename std::result_of<std::tuple_cat(tuple_holder_type::tuple_type,std::tuple<B>) >::type
```

but only got error messages

```
test.cpp:9:85: error: template argument 1 is invalid
test.cpp:9:86: error: expected identifier before '::' token
test.cpp:10:1: error: expected initializer before 'func'
```

the question: what do i put instead of the question marks for this to work

bonus q: why does it work

**EDIT**
forgot to mention i need such a way i can put the resulting type in a `typedef`, resulting in something like

```
template <typename tuple_holder_type, typename B>
struct tuple_appender {
    typedef ??? return_type;
    return_type operator() /*...*/
}
```

thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11 you can use `decltype` like this:

```
template <typename tuple_holder_type, typename B>
auto
func(tuple_holder_type h, B b)
    -> decltype(std::tuple_cat(h.a,std::make_tuple(b)))
{
    return std::tuple_cat(h.a,std::make_tuple(b));
}
```

In the C++1y working draft, you can drop the `decltype` like this:

```
template <typename tuple_holder_type, typename B>
auto
func(tuple_holder_type h, B b)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(h.a,std::make_tuple(b));
}
```

And here is how you can get the return type of `func` and put it in a `typedef`, no matter how `func`'s return type is coded:

```
template <typename tuple_holder_type, typename B>
struct tuple_appender {
    typedef decltype(func(std::declval<typename tuple_holder_type::tuple_type>(),
                          std::declval<std::tuple<B>>())) return_type;
};
```

`std::declval<T>()` is just a way to get an rvalue expression of type `T` without having to default construct one, like `T()`.  You may not want to assume that `T` is default constructible.  You can also get an lvalue expression of `T` with `declval<T&>()`, or a const lvalue expression with `declval<const T&>()`, etc.

Comment: thank you, but i cant use such `decltype` in a typedef, any way to do that?

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment.  Are you saying that your compiler does not support `decltype` and you need a workaround?

Comment: eventually `func` is a member function, and i want to expose its return type via a typedef, check the updated question, sorry

Comment: ok i replaced the `func` with `std::tuple_cat` and it works just like i wanted, thank you very much (note to self: look into `declval` once again)